# Cast Game Manager Samples

Tags: ios, google-cast

I've been trying to get the Google Cast Game Manager for iOS up and running, but haven't had success. According to the docs it should be as simple as:

-Launch iOS sender
-Call initWithSessionID:
-Wait for gameManagerChannelDidConnect:

The problem is that I never get gameManagerChannelDidConnect. I've tried both subclassing GCKGameManagerChannel, and simply implementing its Delegate. I haven't been connected, or hit any of the failure methods. It's not at all obvious what's going wrong.

While the documentation is good, it feels like it has some holes that could be patched with code samples. When can we expect to see samples for the receiver, iOS, and Android?

---EDIT---
Connecting to the same receiver from Android seem to work just fine, so the problem appears to be related to the iOS client framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for trying this out!

When you created the GCKGameManagerChannel (which extends GCKCastChannel) with initWithSessionID did you also add the GCKGameManagerChannel to the GCKDeviceManager with addChannel?

e.g.

```
...
channel = [[GCKGameManagerChannel alloc] initWithSessionID:...];
channel.delegate = ...;
[deviceManager addChannel:channel];
...
```

If that doesn't fix the problem, could you share some code to help  diagnose the problem?

In any case, we'll update the docs with the addChannel step.

With regards to code samples - stay tuned. Sorry for the delay, but they will be coming soon! Keep an eye on https://github.com/googlecast/